# DISTINCTROW by id

Tags: mysql

[image]

SELECT
DISTINCTROW ProductsId AS pid,( SELECT SUM(QuantityByID) WHERE ProductsId=pid )
FROM
cartitem

I want to get this result

```
ProductId Quantity 
7             7 
13            2 
14            2 
9             1
```

Comment: what do you want to get? please explain further.

Comment: Replace `DISTINCTROW` with `DISTINCT` and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help without a question but I think you want a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ProductsId as pid, SUM(QuantityByID) 
FROM products
GROUP BY ProductsId
```

This will give the sum of quantity for each product id.